# Three.js line disappears if one point is outside of the camera's view

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a line as explained in the docs:
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Line.

But when one of the line points is outside of the camera's view, the line disappears.

I also tried to use https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine, but I still have the same problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you modify the line vertices after rendering the line? If not, please show your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you update the vertices of your line, you must also update the bounding sphere of your line for frustum culling to work correctly.

```
line.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

Alternatively, you can prevent frustum culling of your line by setting

```
line.frustumCulled = false;
```

three.js r.75