# THREE.js object cloned outside of frustum

Tags: javascript, three.js, line

In my program there is a mesh made of lines that I clone, change the vertices up, add to an array, and then add to the scene as growing conga line of shapes. The problem is the cloned shapes seem to abide by the same frustum as the original shape, so if I look at the beginning of the conga line, I can see it, but if I look at the end (and the beginning is out of view) the whole thing disappears.

I can't find a "needsUpdate" parameter that affects the frustrum, other than frustrumCulled, but I don't want to disable frustrum culling because I don't want to render the shape when I'm not looking at it!

Did I miss something?

Here is the section of code that "animates" the conga line. Right now it just adds the lines forever, but that's just temporary until I get it working.

```
    this.blurb = function( scene ) { // function is called every frew frames to add a new shape

if ( blurbShapes && blurbShapes.length ) { // checks if the array is already populated by shapes

// makes a clone of the last geometry in the array and its mesh
    blurbCopy = blurbShapes[ blurbShapes.length - 1 ].geometry.clone();
    blurbMaterialCopy = blurbShapes[ blurbShapes.length - 1 ].material.clone();

// randomly jitters the vertices of the geometry a bit for variety
    for ( var i = 0; i < blurbCopy.vertices.length; i++ ) {

        blurbCopy.vertices[i].x += Math.random() - 0.5;
        blurbCopy.vertices[i].y += Math.random() - 0.5;
        blurbCopy.vertices[i].z += Math.random() - 2;
    }

// closes the loop by making the first vertex look at the last one
    blurbCopy.vertices[0] = blurbCopy.vertices[ blurbCopy.vertices.length - 1 ];
    blurbMaterialCopy.color.offsetHSL ( 0.01, 0, 0 );

// update vertex information -- but this doesn't seem to update where the camera thinks the geometry is!
    blurbCopy.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

// add the shape to the array
    blurbShapes.push( new THREE.Line( blurbCopy, blurbMaterialCopy ) );
    scene.add( blurbShapes[ blurbShapes.length - 1 ] );

} else { // first time

    color = new THREE.Color();
    color.setHSL( Math.random(), 0.7, 0.8 );
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: color } ),
    geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 32, 32 );

    // Remove center vertex and make it equal to the last vertex
    geometry.vertices[0] = geometry.vertices[ geometry.vertices.length - 1 ];
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    blurbShapes.push( new THREE.Line( geometry, material ) );
    scene.add( blurbShapes[0] );
}
```

}

Edit: Added comments for reading.

And here's pictures for context. In the first the conga line of lines is completely visible; the "first" line is on the far right edge of the image, half showing. In the second image I look slightly left of the "first" line, so that it is out of view, and the entire array disappears.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code or a part of your code ?

Comment: Hmm I have a problem in that I can't use pointer-lock-controls in a jsfiddle (because the zframe of the demo doesn't allow for mouse control like that, so I won't be able to make a demo. I'll just add my code above.

Comment: Share here a or some parts of code you think it's related, give to the community a point of start to help you, especially with Three.js ;-)

Comment: added! thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you add screenshots ?

Comment: if i undertand well, you want to "extrude" the cloned shape manually and change the position of the verticles with another frustrum ?

Comment: Added some images to help. the extrusion works fine, the issue is all of the lines that I have added after the first are still subject to the same frustrum as the first one. Probably because the clone was "deep" enough to copy some of the properties but not others. I'm not sure how to de-link the behaviour though.

Comment: hm ok i see, im searching a way to do it right, i know three.js but i'm not so good neither for this kind of issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497763/three-js-line-disappears-if-one-point-is-outside-of-the-cameras-view.

Comment: Crap! computeBoundingSphere(); !!! Thanks WestLangley, love your work! Sorry I didn't have a better question for you :(. And thanks pirs for the help.

Comment: @WestLangley It seems to be related